# Mocking an object before ApplicationReadyEvent

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have a service that runs on a @Scheduled, as such, I need some classes to be initialized as soon as possible so they are ready when the first scheduled window triggers.

I have a client class that has the following small initialization code:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    private void init() {
        if(auth != null){
            auth.getToken();
            instanceURL = token.getInstanceUrl();
        }
        if(urlUtils !=null){
            urlUtils.setServiceUrl();
        }
    }
```

Everything worked perfectly and the world was in peace. Then the unit test nation attacked and I ran into some issues.

While unit testing this class, I need to mock the RestTemplate it uses, the issue is, this piece of code runs before I can mock anything on my unit test, and as such I can't mock the RestTemplate call that is used in `auth.getToken()` before it is called and throw a NullPointerException up.

I've tried putting the mock in an ApplicationEvent that would trigger before the ApplicationReadyEvent in the unit test class, like ApplicationStartedEvent, but that obviously didn't work.

I am starting to get the feeling that this is a code smell, but it doesn't feel like bad design to me.

I can't move the initialization code outside the class, as the `auth` and `urlUtils` are instances of two inner classes (which make sense to be inner classes as it is only used by this client).

I could put a conditional on the event and have it disabled for the test profile, but I do need the code to run, so that wouldn't solve the problem either.

Any ideas of what to do? I am up for refactoring, but I don't think I should move the auth and urlUtils classes outside the client class...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the problem, noting it here in case anyone else runs into this.

The `@BeforeAll` from Junit5 allows you to run code before the spring context initialization.

That technically answers my question but did not solve the problem, as I then ran into the issue where my mocked object was not being injected into the client and was being overwritten by a spring created `@MockBean`. Though about manually registering the mocked object with the SpringContext but I am not sure that would be possible as the context was not ready by the time @BeforeAll runs.

That did gave me the idea of returning the mock as a bean from a `@TestConfiguration`.

So, this is what solved the issue:

1 - Have a `@TestConfiguration` class that returns the mocked RestTemplate bean. The preparation has to be done inside the configuration code

```
@Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        String auth_url = "http://localhost";
        SFDCOAuthToken token = new SFDCOAuthToken();
        token.setInstanceUrl("http://localhost");
        RestTemplate restTemplateMock = mock(RestTemplate.class);
        when(restTemplateMock.exchange(eq(auth_url), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(), eq(SFDCOAuthToken.class)))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(token, HttpStatus.OK));
       return restTemplateMock;
    }
```

2 - Remove the `@MockBean` from the RestTemplate in the test class, otherwise that bean will take priority over the one in the configuration

3 - Grab the mocked bean from the context in the test class so you can add more stubs during the tests (the context can simply be retrieved with an `@Autowire ApplicationContext` in the test class)

```
@BeforeEach
    void init(){
        restTemplateMock = ctx.getBean(RestTemplate.class);
    }
```